Polars .get expression doesn't works when using within agg in group_by_dynamic
Looks like .get expression works wrong if every!=period in group_by_dynamic.
This is a minimal replication of the issue:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'time':pl.date_range(pl.date(2021,1,1), pl.date(2021,1,8), eager=True),
    'data': pl.arange(8, eager=True)
    })

df_grouped = df.group_by_dynamic(
    index_column="time", 
    every="2d", 
    period="3d",
    start_by='datapoint',
).agg(
    data=pl.col('data'),
    get_1_bad=pl.col('data').get(1),
    get_1_good=pl.col('data').shift(-1).get(0),
)

print(df, df_grouped)

and the outputs are

┌────────────┬──────┐
│ time       ┆ data │
│ ---        ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ i64  │
╞════════════╪══════╡
│ 2021-01-01 ┆ 0    │
│ 2021-01-02 ┆ 1    │
│ 2021-01-03 ┆ 2    │
│ 2021-01-04 ┆ 3    │
│ 2021-01-05 ┆ 4    │
│ 2021-01-06 ┆ 5    │
│ 2021-01-07 ┆ 6    │
│ 2021-01-08 ┆ 7    │
└────────────┴──────┘
┌────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│ time       ┆ data      ┆ get_1_bad ┆ get_1_good │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ date       ┆ list[i64] ┆ i64       ┆ i64        │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
│ 2021-01-01 ┆ [0, 1, 2] ┆ 1         ┆ 1          │
│ 2021-01-03 ┆ [2, 3, 4] ┆ 2         ┆ 3          │
│ 2021-01-05 ┆ [4, 5, 6] ┆ 4         ┆ 5          │
│ 2021-01-07 ┆ [6, 7]    ┆ 5         ┆ 7          │
└────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴────────────┘

shift(x), get(0) and get(-1) work correctly, so I can fix the issue with .shift(-1).get(0) but .get(x) in general does not work for some reason.
Am I making some mistake in using polars or is it a library bug? polars version is '0.20.25'

df.group_by_dynamic(...).agg(pl.col("data").get(x)) not returning the same result as df.group_by_dynamic(...).agg(pl.col("data")).select(pl.col("data").list.get(x)) seems like a bug. It might be worthwhile to raise an issue on polars' GitHub page.

Thanks for your feedback. Done it https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/16116
